# i want to store elements in matrix and call number wise but there call in workspace it seems undefined function and consider only last entry

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matlab-guide

```
for d=1:18
   parent=bitand(entry(d), 2.^(7:-1:0)) > 0;
end
```

(there is entry(18*1) matrix it has 18 decimal number)

when i apply this code than this all rows named as 'parent' but i want to call parent(11)it shown error how i call particular raw from this created parent matrix and only parent call than i shown only last entry as consider value

Comment: You are over-writing `parent` every time through the loop. Use `parent(d) = ...`

Comment: if use parent(d) than 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.' error @Suever

Comment: OK well then you need to use `parent(d,:)` or `parent{d}`. Please read the documentation on accessing array data.

Comment: in next       step                                                                               swapping=[3 4]                                                              newpm11(swapping)=pa(1,:)(swapping)                                                 -here i can't use pa(1 , :) compulsary need to define pa1=pa(1,:) this element...@Suever